# android fragment's textView is not updating new information

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a MainActivty and 2 different fragments(Fragment A&B). What I want to do is when user clicks something on fragment A, it will automatically swipe to fragment B and also update a textView in Fragment B. But the problem now is that it won't update the textView in Fragment B. Here is my code

> MainActivity

```
public class MainRegisterCompleteInfo extends AppIntro implement FragmentA.OnFragmentInteractionListener
    ,FragmentB.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    addSlide(new FragmentA());
    addSlide(new FragmentB());

    fragmentB = new FragmentB();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fragmentB, "fragmentB").commit();


    //int currentPage = pager.getCurrentItem();
    //Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(currentPage), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}

//This is a interface from fragment A
@Override
public void setUniversityName(String universityName) {
    pager.setCurrentItem(3);
    FragmentB.updateText(universityName);
 }
}
```

> Fragment A

```
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void setUniversityName(String universityName);
}
```

> Fragment B

```
public void updateText(String text){
    txtTest.setText(text);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), txtTest.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I have tried to search several similar questions but still couldn't solve it. The textView in Fragment B just won't update the text. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you check by making the log within this function before textview set as new text?

Comment: @DPrince Yes, I have already checked. I can confirm that the text is not null

Comment: Do you get a Toast message on calling this function?

Comment: @DPrince yes I also get a Toast from the function, the string value did went to fragment B, But the textView just won't update it.